# How to get unique feature count from a field w.r.t another field using ogrinfo?

Tags: qgis, ogr

We have some 40 folders which has two - three tab files in each folder. Table structure will be the same for all the tab files. What i would like to extract is Feature Count, LineNo (will be 0,1,2,3,etc..), StationNo (Will be from 0 - 85). LineNo and StationNo are related. For LineNo "0" = StationNo will be "0,1,2 upto 85" and again for LineNo "1" = StationNo will be "0,1,2,3 upto 85" (see the image).

[image]

So how to extract these informations using ogrinfo ?

Answer (score 1):

GDAL supports the use of SQL for all datasources and especially the SQLite dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html is quite powerful. This should work for you:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select LineNo, StationNo, count(*) from your_layer_name group by LineNo, StationNo order by 1,2" your_tab_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stucked with this from yesterday. Actually, it worked like a charm. But the problem is, it is listing all the features and shows count for each LineNo.       

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  LineNo (Integer) = 0
  StationNo (Real) = 0.5
  count(*) (Integer) = 1

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  LineNo (Integer) = 0
  StationNo (Real) = 1
  count(*) (Integer) = 1

What i want is for LineNo = 0, it should list how many unique StationNo's are there. Something like 
LineNo (Integer) = 0
StationNo Count = 171. I've used "Select DISTINCT". But still the result is the same as that of the previous one.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not quite understand what was your aim. But now you know how to execute SQL queries with ogrinfo and the rest is only making a proper query. I would import one tab file into Spatialite with ogr2ogr `-f "SQLite" -dsco spatialite=yes` and use Spatialite-gui for building and testing the query. Once the query gives a desired result in Spatialite-gui you can insert it into your ogrinfo scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Through you answer, actaully it opened new doors for me. One final question. In the shell, i've used this command: For /R "Folder_Path" %f in (*.tab) do ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco spatiallite = yes "%f">>D:\Test\Dummy.sqlite. It has created Dummy.sqlite. But in the command shell it shows "No source datasource provided". Could you able to tell me whats wrong with this command.

Comment: For writing all tab files into one Spatialite db, each into own table use something like `For %%f in (*.tab) do (ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco spatialite=yes -append Dummy.sqlite %%f)` and for collecting all tab files into one table use `For %%f in (*.tab) do (ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco spatialite=yes -append Dummy.sqlite %%f -nln collect)` Do not care about warnings and read ogr2ogr manual.